# addAxiom add only prefix form OWL API

Tags: java, owl-api

I build small ontology from string in Manchester syntax where I use prefixes. But then, when I use getAxioms() method and want to add one of these axioms to other ontology (in default format), classes and individuals aren't in IRI form (it stays in form prefix:something). Can I change it somehow?

Comment: Hi, the question needs more details to be answerable. How you build the ontology, what the ontology contains, and what the axioms look like when added to the other ontology - this would help understand what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I've already solved it. The problem was in my part of code, because I didn't check input, and forgot to delete < and > from IRI.